# Convenient logging with protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to make logging easier for devs writing selenium tests with protractor.

I'm looking at [selenium-webdriver/lib/logging](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/logging.html) and am trying to figure out how to make a convenient logging system.

Here is an example spec:

```
it('should NOT show welcome before login', () => {
  // convenient log here
  expect(homepage.logo.isPresent()).toBe(true);
  // log message that would occur after expect 
  expect(homepage.welcomeText.isPresent()).toBe(false);
  // final log message
});
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

I'm trying to avoid having to do (below) for every log message.

```
homepage.welcomeText.isPresent().then(() => console.log('foo bar'));
```

Comment: You might ask yourself why you need that much logging. In your example, you are logging three messages for only two actions. Do you really need to log something on success? If your validation fails, it will be logged. I would focus more on making sure that when something fails that you can easily trace back to the error. I don't know about protractor or your IDE but I find that to be much more important for me than logs full of success messages. If you do feel like you need some milestone type logging to get your bearings, log on page transitions or something like that.

Comment: Does `expect()` not have a message option? The *Unit type Asserts typically are overloaded... one with and one without a message. I always add a descriptive message for what I'm validating and that, with the stack trace, is generally good enough.

Comment: @JeffC, I don't 'need' the logging per se. I can live without it. I'm trying to make it a little easier for ease of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a npm package -  [log4js-protractor-appender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-protractor-appender) which will solve your problem.It is built specially for Protractor based environments and it places all logger command in Protractor Control flow and resolves Protractor promises before logging.

Since Protractor executes all commands in a Control Flow , and all non protractor commands dont get executed in the order we like. So regular logging will need an extra effort from us to chain a non-protractor command to a protractor command

Example:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function _logValue(url){
  logger.info("The url is" + url);
});
```

But [log4js-protractor-appender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-protractor-appender) enabled to write something like this directly - `browser.logger.info('Displayed text is:', browser.getCurrentUrl());`

For more details on how to implement this- Please check my blog post - [How to implements logs for Protractor/JavaScript based Test Automation Frameworks](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/04/how-to-implements-logs-for-protractorjavascript-based-test-automation-frameworks/)

Comment: Looks like the last link (of your blog) is broken.

Answer (score 1):

For expects you can use toBeTruthy or Falsy and include message there. It would log if something goes wrong. Page Object pattern says you must not have weddriver methods in spec files meaning you may cretae method which would verify something present or not and then() log there like in your example. Also you can implement asyncLog function. console.log() method goes to Stack and executes before protractor methods since protractor's Control Flow or Managed Promise. It wraps every protractor method in deffered promise which puts it in callback queue which executes only after stack is empty. Take a look at next code. I didn't try it out for Protractor though but you can get the idea.

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();

function asyncLog(message) {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(message));
}

console.log('Start');

promise
.then(() => console.log('This is then'))

asyncLog('This is Callback Queue log');

console.log('This is Call Stack log');

promise
.then(() => console.log('This is another then'))
```